# Server not reading data

Tags: java, sockets, server

I had modified the Java Socket Tutorials code to allow the client to send a string array and the server passes the array back with the strings in the array changed. It works fine.

Now I am trying to create a server class that behaves as a server component. The component basically only receives data from the client and prints the client data. However, the server accepts the connection but does not reading. Hence, to see what was happening, I tried to just run a server socket from main. Even that is not working. I am not sure why the tutorial code works but not when I do the exact thing in my code. I do not understand the reason for such peculiar behavior.

Following is the Java Tutorial Code for Server

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Server {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

   int portNumber = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

    try 
    (
                ServerSocket serverSocket =
                    new ServerSocket(Integer.parseInt(args[0]));
                Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();     

                ObjectInputStream objIn = new     ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
                ObjectOutputStream objOut = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream()); 
    ) {
                String str[][] = (String [][])objIn.readObject();

                if(str != null)
                {   for(int i = 0; i<str.length;i++)
                        for(int j = 0; j<str[i].length;j++)
                            System.out.println(str[i][j]);

                    for(int i = 0; i<str.length;i++)
                        for(int j = 0; j<str[i].length;j++)
                            str[i][j] ="Success";
                    objOut.writeObject(str);
                }

    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException ecp) {
        System.out.println("Exception caught when trying to listen on port "
            + portNumber + " or listening for a connection");
        System.out.println(ecp.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

The following is the client from Java Tutorial

```
public class EchoClient {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    if (args.length != 2) {
        System.err.println(
            "Usage: java EchoClient <host name> <port number>");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    String hostName = args[0];
    int portNumber = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

    try (
        Socket echoSocket = new Socket(hostName,portNumber);    
        ObjectOutputStream objOut = new ObjectOutputStream(echoSocket.getOutputStream());
        ObjectInputStream objIn = new ObjectInputStream(echoSocket.getInputStream());   
        PrintWriter out =
            new PrintWriter(echoSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        BufferedReader in =
            new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(echoSocket.getInputStream()));
        BufferedReader stdIn =
            new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(System.in))

    ) {
       String str[][] = new String[8][8];
       for(int i = 0; i<str.length;i++)
        for(int j = 0; j<str[i].length;j++)
            str[i][j] = "Test";
       objOut.writeObject(str);
        System.out.println("String array sent");

       str = (String[][])objIn.readObject();
       for(int i = 0; i<str.length;i++)
        for(int j = 0; j<str[i].length;j++)
            System.out.println(str[i][j]);


    } catch (UnknownHostException  e) {
        System.err.println("Don't know about host " + hostName);
        System.exit(1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to " +
            hostName);
        System.exit(1);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
}
```

Now the following is my simple server attempt which does not read when EchoClient sends data. It connects but not read.

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Server 
{

public static void main (String[] args)
{

    try {
        ServerSocket serv = new ServerSocket(8000);
        Socket client = serv.accept();

        ObjectInputStream objin = new  ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());
        String[][] str = (String[][]) objin.readObject();

        for(int i = 0; i<str.length;i++)
            for(int j = 0; j<str[i].length;j++)
                str[i][j] ="Success";

        System.out.println(str[0][0]);
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Please let me know where I am going wrong. Note the Java tutorial classes EchoServer and EchoClient work as expected. But I am unable to replicate it on my own. The Server class accepts EchoClient but does not read.

EDIT:Following is my fixed attempt. This works as intended.

Server class:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Server 
{
ServerSocket serverSocket;
Socket clientSocket;
String hostname;
int portNo = 8000;
String clientData;
int count = 0;
public Server()
{
    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNo);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public void startReceiving()
{
    try {
        if(clientSocket == null)
        {   clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("Client Connected");
        }

                ObjectInputStream objIn = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());

                //String strtemp[][];
                    String data;
                while(true)
                {
                    if((data = (String)objIn.readObject()) != null)
                    {
                        this.clientData = data;
                        System.out.println(this.clientData);

                        break;
                    }

                    /*if((strtemp = (String[][]) objIn.readObject())!= null)
                    {
                        str = strtemp;
                        System.out.println("received data");
                        for(int i = 0; i<str.length;i++)
                            for(int j = 0; j<str[i].length;j++)
                                System.out.println(str[i][j]);
                    }
                    else
                        System.out.println("no data received");*/
                }
                sendData();

            } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                //e.printStackTrace();
                try {
                    clientSocket.close();
                    clientSocket = null;
                    startReceiving();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

            }


}
public void sendData()
{
    /*for(int i = 0; i<str.length;i++)
        for(int j = 0; j<str[i].length;j++)
            str[i][j] ="Success";*/
            this.clientData = "client request response" + count;
            count++;
            ObjectOutputStream objOut;
            try {
                objOut = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
                objOut.writeObject(this.clientData);
                objOut.flush();
                startReceiving();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

}
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    Server server = new Server();
    server.startReceiving();

}
}
```

Following is the client:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class TestClient
{
Socket connection;
String hostname = "localhost";
int portNo = 8000;
String incomingData;
int count;
public TestClient()
{
    try {
        connection = new Socket(hostname,portNo);
        count = 0;
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public void receiveData()
{
    ObjectInputStream in;
    try {
        in = new ObjectInputStream(this.connection.getInputStream());
        String serverMessage;
        while (true)
        {
            if((serverMessage = (String)in.readObject()) != null)
                {
                System.out.println(serverMessage);
                break;
                }
        }
        if(count < 5)
            sendData();
        else
            {
                in.close();
                this.connection.close();
            }

    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //

}
public void sendData()
{
    try {
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        out.writeObject("Client request" + count);
        out.flush();
        count++;
        receiveData();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
public static void main(String args[])
{
    TestClient testClient = new TestClient();
    testClient.sendData();

}
}
```

Comment: Well the first thing I notice is that the "client" is expecting to read input from the server, but your modified sever doesn't send any.

Comment: But even if I comment it out, the server does not even print the data received.

Answer (score 0):

Your client creates an `ObjectInputStream` but the server doesn't create a corresponding `ObjectOutputStream`, so the client blocks waiting for the object stream header that is never sent.

Also you should get rid of all the `Readers` and `Writers.` You can't combine different kinds of reader/writer/stream over the same socket.

Also your server doesn't close the socket properly.

Also the error message 'couldn't get I/O for ...' is meaningless. I know it comes from the Java Tutorial, and I complained to them about it decades ago, but you should never make up your own error message and throw away the one that comes with the exception like this.

Answer (score 0):

You did not understand properly how this application is designed.

You removed the part where you send str[i][j] but still set it to success in the loop, this is illogical. At first run, the server will read nothing, therefore it will never set any values to the array and this is why `System.out.println(str[0][0])` print nothing.

You have to understand that in the example from the tutorial, the first loop read what is received

```
for(int i = 0; i<str.length;i++)
    for(int j = 0; j<str[i].length;j++)
        System.out.println(str[i][j]);
```

Then the second loop simply write success everywhere and re-send the data to the `EchoClient`.

```
for(int i = 0; i<str.length;i++)
    for(int j = 0; j<str[i].length;j++)
        str[i][j] ="Success";
objOut.writeObject(str);
```

Using this `main`

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    int portNumber = 8000;
    try {
        ServerSocket serv = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
        Socket client = serv.accept();

        ObjectInputStream objin = new  ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());
        ObjectOutputStream objOut = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream()); 
        String str[][] = (String[][]) objin.readObject();

        if(str != null)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i<str.length;i++)
                for(int j = 0; j<str[i].length;j++)
                    System.out.println(str[i][j]);

            for(int i = 0; i<str.length;i++)
                for(int j = 0; j<str[i].length;j++)
                    str[i][j] ="Success";
            objOut.writeObject(str);
        }

        System.out.println(str[0][0]);
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Which is the one you used, but where I re-added the second loop and writing, will print on both Client and Server.

You should also consider handling the `Socket` termination in a finally block to make sure it is closed whatever happen to your program.

```
try
{
...
}
catch(IOEXception e)
{
...
}
finally
{
    if(socket != null)
        socket.close();
}
```

Make sure to declare the socket outside of the try scope so it is accessible in the finally.

Comment: Yes you are right that I should not have changed the string to success since I was not sending the data back from the server. However, I still do not understand why the server won't read the string array sent. Does the server always needs to send data back for successful read?

Comment: @user3213348 Because the client never sends it. It gets stuck at `new ObjectInputStream(...).` See my answer.

Comment: I have got the things to work and have modified it. But I still do not understand why it was not reading. EchoClient does create an ObjectOutputStream and writes the object. The Server also creates an ObjectInputStream to read the object. Hence, I am still not clear about the bug, even though things are working.

Comment: @user3213348 because, you ommited the creation of an ObjectOutputStream in the server, so the client was waiting forever and never received any data.

Comment: But ObjectOutputStream in the server is used when the server is sending the data back. Why does it interfere with the reading the data? For example, the Java tutorial server reads data from its ObjectInputStream.

Comment: Because of the stream header. If you want to defer construction of the object output stream in the server, you also have to defer construction of the object input stream in the client. It's usually best to construct the object output streams first, at both ends.